# ASP.NET MVC best practice for creation in one transaction

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am working on a MVC web application that should have a creation dialog for some kind of entry.

It should be possible to enter some text information as well as upload documents, images, videos, etc.

The following problem arises:

Are there any general best practices for uploading the whole bunch of information at ONCE? The object should not be created in the database until the user really decides to submit the information.

I thought about some solutions

- Storing the uploads with the FileAPI in the browser
- Immediate AJAX-Upload when selecting files. But where to "cache" the file on the server? The entry is not in the Database since I am creating the object.
- Creation of a database entry when opening the form? But this would result in junk in the database

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Thank you
Kind regards

Comment: Asp.Net MVC isn't stateless, HTTP is stateless....

Comment: you're right, but I don't want to have a state apart from user sessions on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this approach will be good to follow.

1. Have Session cache which will keep the files-bytes in server memory.
2. When user comes on the upload page, clear it.
3. When user uploads the files, save file-bytes on server session cache.
4. When user *really wants to upload* files - say - submit files - kind of button, get the files from session cache and upload in the database.
5. Clears the session cache when its saved in database.

In case of large files, like videos, you would like to create a temporary folder(per user), save files inside that folder - instead of session cache, and clear/delete the folder after the files are saved in database.

Comment: what about large files, for example videos? They would take up the whole memory and maybe be swapped? Should the session be stored in the database?